# Nodejs - SPDY push on request error

Tags: node.js, spdy

I am having trouble launching my Node app. I get "TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined" error.
Here is my code:

```
spdy.createServer(credentials, app).listen(app.get('port'), function(req, res) {
 res.push('public/js/bootstrap.min.js', {'content-type': 'application/javascript'}, function(err, stream) {
        stream.end('alert("hello from push stream!")');
      });
 res.push('public/js/jquery.min.js', {'content-type': 'application/javascript'}, function(err, stream) {
        stream.end();
      });
 res.push('public/css/bootstrap.min.css', {'content-type': 'text/css'}, function(err, stream) {
        stream.end();
      });

      // write main response body and terminate stream
      res.end('Hello World!');

console.log('Express HTTPS SPDY server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
}   );
```

I am running SDPY version 1.19.2 and NodeJS version 0.10.25.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825307/nodejs-spdy-push-on-request-error?rq=1#comment33043670_21829740), you are serving with HTTP/1.1. You need to be serving with HTTP2/SPDY for push to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// set the root path of Express server
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public');

app.use(function(req, res) {
  // your res.push code is here.
  var stream = res.push('/js/bootstrap.min.js', {'content-type': 'application/javascript'});
  stream.on('acknowledge', function() {
    console.log('stream ACK');
  });
  stream.on('error', function() {
    console.log('stream ERR');
  });
  stream.end('alert("stream SUCCESSFUL");');
  res.end('<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>');
});

spdy.createServer(credentials, app).listen(app.get('port'));
```

The callback function passed to `listen()` function takes no arguments. see line 49, file [stream-test.js](https://github.com/indutny/node-spdy/blob/master/test/unit/stream-test.js)

Comment: The error has stopped appearing. But when I look at the Network inspector of Firefox 27, I still see the files being fetched after the HTML file. I am trying to make them download at the same time.

Comment: what's the response returned by the server?

Comment: content-length:852
content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8
etag:"-1294749726"
status:200 OK
version:HTTP/1.1
x-powered-by:Express

Comment: I've update the code. It should work now. This code is tested with Firefox 27 and Chrome 32.

Comment: I've just tested with Firefox 27 and Chrome 32 with no success. No logs show up nor does the alert message.

Comment: Assumes that the JavaScript file is in the sub directory `public`. Set the root path of the Express server to `__dirname+'/public'`. Change the URL of the JavaScript file to `/js/bootstrap.min.js`. See the latest code above.

Comment: I've checked that of coarse. Maybe its the way I benchmark that is wrong, I'm using the integrated Network inspector from both Firefox and Chrome and I suppose that when push is enabled the files are downloaded at the exact time as the HTML (/) file. But what I get instead is just normal async download after the HTML file parsing. BNUHERO, I am very grateful for your time.

Comment: This is what I get from Chrome Sessions(chrome://net-internals/#events&q=type:SPDY_SESSION%20is:active): SPDY_SESSION_SYN_STREAM::Fin=TRUE, method= GET. Is Fin= TRUE means that its push?